# How to add  a DataGrid to a DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, datatemplate

I need to add a DataGrid to a DataGridTempateColumn,so i did this, but it dosen't work correctly,I don't know if i really can add a DataGrid to a DataGridTempateColumn?

```
<datagrid>
....
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True"                    ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectCollection}">
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Spec.Rev}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
                                <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Spec}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>

        </DataGrid>
     </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
...
</DataGrid>
```

EDited:
while the ProjectCollection is null,we can't see the dataGrid,as you see in row 2 in the picture!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this will work. You will get the `InvalidOperationException` - `Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.` since you are setting the ItemsSource for the innner Grid and at the same time you are adding childs to the DataGrid.

Add the columns to the Columns DP of your dataGrid like this and it will work as you desired -

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                 CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectCollection}">
           <DataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Spec.Rev}" Width="*"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Spec}" Width="*"/>
           </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
     </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use `DataGrid` you can use `ListView` with view `GridView`.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Complex Data">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>                    
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectCollection}">
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}" />
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: i'v already did,but it had the same result. when i set it's  HeadersVisibility="None",i just see a single readonly column!

Comment: Show me what is plugged into the ItemsSource.

Comment: kmatyaszek : `ProjectCollection = new ObservableCollection<Project>(a List of Projects);`

Comment: @ kmatyaszek :Yes,thanks,but there is another problem,while the ProjectCollection is empty,it shows an empty row,i attached a picture,you can see what i mean

Comment: @raha- That's how it works. DataGrid with 0 items will show as blank. What you desired in that case?